# Replace Specific Instance

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm completely new to RegEx and could really use some help with my delimma. I have a large text file of IP addresses and corresponding Hosts.

eg.

```
157.55.33.47 msnbot-157-55-33-47.search.msn.com
157.56.93.62 msnbot-157-56-93-62.search.msn.com
etc...
```

I need a find and replace algorithm that apeends to the beginning and end of each line and replaces the delimeter, which in this case is just a space.

eg. the ouput after running the regex should be

```
'text1' 157.55.33.47 'text2' msnbot-157-55-33-47.search.msn.com 'text3'
'text1' 157.56.93.62 'text2' msnbot-157-56-93-62.search.msn.com 'text3'
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Find what:

```
^([\S]+)\s([\S]+)$
```

Replace with:

```
'text1' $1 'text2' $2 'text3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Macro for this instead of a regex. Record keystrokes on the first line. I'm on a Mac right now, so I can't be sure this is right, but it should be close to:

```
Home, [type 'text1'], CTRL+RightArrow [repeat 7 times], [type 'text2],
space, End, space, [type 'text3'], DownArrow
```

Once your Macro is recorded, re-run your Macro for the entire file. Again, I can't see the exact options, but it will be something like the following:

Go to `Macros>Run a Macro Multiple Times...`, select `Current recorded macro`, and `Run until the end of file.`